# How to get the most recent date from a table

Tags: c#, date

I have code where I'm querying something from my table which has a property called `CreateDate`. I just want to get the object with the most recent date. This is what I have:

```
var post = UnitOfWork.TableName.Query(postFilter);
```

I tried using a Max function like this:

```
var post = UnitOfWork.TableName.Query(postFilter).Max(x => x.CreatedDate);
```

but that returns just the date.

How do I return a whole object that is the most recent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to order by the date and take one:

```
var post = UnitOfWork.TableName.Query(postFilter)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```